# Spatial Mapping in Unity for Hololens 1

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, hololens, mrtk

Good morning,
I am trying to install the Mixed Reality Toolkit for Hololens 1. I need to do a Spatial Mapping in Unity and I would like to use a "Spatial Mapping" prefab which should be displayed after Unity configuration with the MRTK tool. Unfortunately, I don’t see the prefab. I enabled the "SpatialPerception" in the Player configuration and simply put "Microsoft Reality Toolkit Foundation" in my project from the MRTK tool. How can I access the Spatial Mapping prefab please?
Thank you.

[image unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It2zs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use spatial mapping in the app, we should enable the Spatial Awareness system in the MixedRealityToolkit profile and register spatial observers to provide mesh data. There is not a Spatial Mapping "prefab" in MRTK. Here is a step by step guide showing how to do that:[Spatial awareness getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/spatial-awareness/spatial-awareness-getting-started?view=mrtkunity-2021-05)

Comment: By the way, Unity 2020 does not support targeting HoloLens (1st gen). HoloLens (1st gen) remain supported in Unity 2019 LTS with Legacy Built-in XR for the full lifecycle of Unity 2019 LTS through mid-2022. For more information, please see: [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version#unity-20194-lts)